How can I use the result of a function which has multiple return types, without being warned about "Incompatible types in assignment"?
This question is in the context of Python 3.12 (so, making use of the latest type hinting features of the language) and the current version of mypy for static type checking.
Consider the example function below, which would return either a complex object or a dict, depending on what you ask the function to do. Is there a way yet in the language of specifying "I know which of the return values this function call is going to give me, when it can return multiple types"?:
def api_request(*args, as_json: bool = False, **kwargs) -> requests.Response | dict:
  response = requests.request(*args, **kwargs)
  if as_json is True:
    return response.json()
  return response

When I go to use this function elsewhere, this fails static type checking (I'm using mypy):
def another_func():
  response = api_request(as_json=True)
  foo = response["foo"]  # error: Value of type "Response | dict[Any, Any]" is not indexable  [index]

This does not work:
  response: dict = api_request(as_json=True)  # error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Response | dict[Any, Any]", variable has type "dict[Any, Any]")  [assignment]

This does, but feels to me to negate the whole point of using type hinting in the first place, because it's not "any type". It's going to return a dict:
  response: Any = api_request(as_json=True)
  foo = response["foo"]

Commenting # type: ignore on the line also works:
  response = api_request(as_json=True)
  foo = response["foo"]  # type: ignore

But again, that feels like cheating / degrading the usefulness of the type-checking.

Why don't you write overloads for the true and false cases separately?

In this case you could write overloads and it could work with a lieral type for the json parameter, but honestly, the best way is usually to simply don't return union types.

Yep, where I got stuck with this I just broke it into api_request and api_request_json which wraps api_request...  My example is just a toy example.  I'm still interested to see if there is a way for the type hinting system in python to handle union return values actually being used as variables... Given the complexity of something like Flask/Werkzeug, they seem to manage it somehow  (Flask responses can be like 5 different things), but reading through all of flask, werkzeug, sansio, I can't figure out how it's being done :-)

@Erinaceous it works the same way it always works, the caller has to be in charge of narrowing types. This could be something like assert isinstance(response, dict).

The static typechecker only knows that the return type could be JSON or a dict. It doesn't know how this relates to any particular Boolean value, unless you use overload and Literal types for the argument of the overload. However, using a runtime value to "choose" the behavior of a function is an anti-pattern. Instead of one function that reacts to a Boolean argument, use the argument to choose which of two separate functions to call.

In this case I'd recommend just removing as_json with the conditional and appending .json() outright to api_request() if needed by the caller.
